# Ошибка в python модуль ffmpeg и pafy: Unable to extract uploader id

Tags: python, ffmpeg

я создаю своего музыкального бота для дискорда.
Сейчас моя задача сделать так, чтобы мой бот мог просто проигрывать видео из YouTube в голосовом канале, где находится автор сообщения.
Чтобы бот проиграл видео надо использовать **префикс:ссылка_на_видео**, однако у меня выводится ошибка, но бот из голосового канала не выходит.

Я пробывал исправить эту ошибку - обновить модуль **ffmpeg**, что не дало мне результатов.

> Ошибка: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OSError: ERROR: Unable to extract uploader id; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import pafy
import asyncio
import ffmpeg

settings = {
    'token': 'скрыт',
    'bot': 'Zyni',
    'id': скрыт,
    'prefix': '!'
}

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.voice_states = True
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'], intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url: str):
    if not ctx.author.voice:
        return await ctx.send("Ты не подключен к голосовому каналу")
    else:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    voice_client = await channel.connect()
    video = pafy.new(url)
    audio = video.getbestaudio()
    audio_url = audio.url
    print(f"Playing {audio.title}")
    player = voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(audio_url))
    while not player.is_done():
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await voice_client.disconnect()

bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Make sure you are using the latest version; see https://yt-dl.org/update on how to update.
```

У вас в ошибке указан сбойный модуль и ссылка на инструкцию по обновлению)

Если не поможет попробуйте использовать [последнюю сборку](https://github.com/ytdl-patched/youtube-dl/releases)

Разработчик уже [знает](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/32226) об ошибке